# Vuex two way data binding with mapGetter helper

Tags: vue.js, vuex, two-way-binding

So i know how Vuex implements two way data binding using set() and get methods on the computed property of the component. i.e return the store state or the relevant geeter in the get() method and commit a mutation in the set method which then mutates the state value. I also know how to use mapGetter() helper from Vuex to simply map Vuex getters to the computed property of the component.

My question is how to implement two way data binding when mapGetter helper is used without writing set and get methods for the computed property.

Answer (score 2):

One of the best vue packages around

```
https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields
```

Taken from the package description

> Enable two-way data binding for form fields saved in a Vuex store.